# Why did Kenobi and Yoda 1v1 Vader and Palpatine?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Kenobi wanted to fight Palpatine as he couldn't stomach the thought of fighting Vader ("as he was a brother").  Yoda dismissed the idea as he knew Kenobi was too weak.  Yoda decided he would fight Palpatine and Kenobi against Vader.  Was he just overconfident?  He thought Kenobi could take care of Vader and he could take care of Palpatine?

Wasn't choosing to 1v1 Vader and Palpatine the extremely risky choice?  What if they both died (Yoda and Kenobi)?  Then what?

Wouldn't the more logical and less risky decision be to jump Palpatine? Then take care of Vader together after?  Or even less risky, jump Vader and double-team Palpatine later?

Either-way I say the most logical choice was to double team one of them (Vader or Palpatine), then regroup, maybe collect a couple other jedi survivors and jump the remaining one.

Comment: Please see my answer with the canon quotes on a linked question

Comment: Ah sorry, can you provide a link? I looked through the search engine for this idea but I didn't see anything after the first couple pages.

Comment: Even on your answers I couldn't find the question:

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A976+%5Bstar-wars%5D+kenobi+yoda

Comment: closing the question inserted the link to the duplicate right at the top of the question. You may need to reload your page to see the "This question already has an answer here:" update.

Comment: Ah sorry for such a newbish comment chain, in my defense this was my first duplicate but thanks!

Comment: no problem. Site mechanics takes a bit of time to figure out :) Good luck!